# sql select allColumns with (no duplicates One Colume) also return count

Tags: c#, sql

I need some help with the query,

I have a products Table. 
I need to select all columns (No Duplicates for 'Barcode') 
also I need to know how many duplicates were found for each 'barcode'...?

Heres What i have:
ID-----BarCode------Date------ProductType------Status------Serial ...etc.....
1------BarAA---------Jan1------Simple-------------Saleble------843573857
2------BarBB--------Jan2------Unqie---------------Saleble------87686585647
3------BarCC--------Jan9------Unqie---------------Saleble------456365677
4------BarCC--------Jan5------Unqie---------------Saleble------3415435437
5------BarCC--------Jan7------Unqie---------------Saleble------fdgsfdg4t
6------BarDD--------Jan6------Unqie---------------Saleble------435tergdf
7------BarDD--------Jan9------Unqie---------------Saleble------mgdnfdfsg
8------BarDD--------Jan4------Unqie---------------Saleble------sdfwr534ew

I need:
count----ID-----BarCode------Date------ProductType------Status------Serial ...etc.....
1---------1------BarAA---------Jan1------Simple-------------Saleble------843573857
1---------2------BarBB--------Jan2------Unqie---------------Saleble------87686585647
3---------3------BarCC--------Jan9------Unqie---------------Saleble------456365677
3---------6------BarDD--------Jan6------Unqie---------------Saleble------435tergdf

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having problems seeing the query you need help with... Can you post your work?

Comment: What does your data set look like? What is your expected result? What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service please provide a specific problem with a
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just a bit of clarification; for the barcodes that are duplicated, do you want just the first serial number, or do you want just the first serial?

Comment: no it dose not matter.. any serial number can show 
because i will open them throught the 'ID' field

Comment: even any ID can show no problem, as long as its one of the IDs in the group of 3 as listed above in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to determine what exactly you mean or you're having trouble with without code to look at. I'm including the T-SQL Code for you'll need to get one row per barcode and also how many duplicates exist per barcode for barcodes that are duplicated.

```
WITH ProductsCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Barcode ORDER BY Barcode) Instance, * 
    FROM 
        dbo.Products
)
SELECT * FROM ProductsCTE WHERE ProductsCTE.Instance = 1;
```

The above code snippet will only get 1 row per unique barcode. So if you can load your products from that query you'll have no duplicates as far as the barcode is concerned.

For determining how many entries you have per barcode, consider the following code.

```
SELECT 
    p.Barcode, COUNT(*) NumberOfEntries
FROM
    dbo.Products p
GROUP BY
    p.Barcode
HAVING -- You can leave the HAVING clause out if you want to include unique ones
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: thank a lot! .. this solved %50 of mu probem.. can you take a look at what i added to the question so you can help me fix the whole problem?